# How To connect 2 Forms?

Tags: forms

Every user of my site must be able to create a first FORM, a first request, where inserts quantities.
Administrator must be able to control these quantities and possibly confirm or modify them.

Then the user must be able to fill out a second FORM, a second request, where insert a number of elements for a field, as many as the amount specified in the first FORM.

Example: if in the first FORM someone entered for PRODOTTO_1 as QUANTITY '= 3, in the second FORM must enter, for PRODOTTO_1, only 3 NAMES taken from a list in the site.
If inserts for PRODOTTO_1 as QUANTITY '= 2, in the second FORM must enter only 2 NAMES for PRODOTTO_1.

How can I try to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance to everyone!!!

Comment: I'm trying to use [EntityForm](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform) and [Entity Construction Kit](https://www.drupal.org/project/eck)....I don't know if is the right way....Any suggestion?